# How to use NSData+Base64Additions.h Objective C class in Swift?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

I need use a function from Objective C in Swift class

```
 -(NSString *)encodeBase64ForData{}
```

In Objective C I call with this form:

```
  #import "NSData+Base64Additions.h"
 [videoPath encodeWrappedBase64ForData]
```

But in Swift, i can't import this class. How can use this encoder?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First hit on google: http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/quick-tips/base64-decoding-in-ios-7-objective-c-and-ios8-swift/

Basically, you don't need to import the category for NSString. You can use the builtin functionality for base64 strings.

```
let plainString = "my string to encode"
let plainData = (plainString as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let base64String = plainData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.fromRaw(0)!)
println(base64String) // Something like bXkgc3RyaW5nIHRvIGVuY29kZQ==
```

Comment: But... this class is used to encode NSdata, not NSString

Comment: @user3745888 True, however in the example you can see that we start out with plainString which is a NSString. I will update the example to be more explicit.

Comment: @user3745888: "Base-64" is for encoding binary data, which is what `NSData` is. `NSString` represents a sequence of characters, not binary data. You can convert a character string into binary data through *string encoding*, where you have to choose which encoding scheme you want.

Comment: If I convert to NSString my NSData I get nil : (NSString(data: myData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)! encodeWrappedBase64ForData isn't same that base64EncodedStringWithOptions.. https://github.com/kailoa/iphone-smtp/blob/master/Classes/NSData%2BBase64Additions.m

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the objective-c bridging header file, and add that import into it. The first time you create an objective c class in a swift project it should prompt you to create, otherwise you have to manually create and set it in your build settings "Objective-C Bridging Header".

More info can be found at: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/MixandMatch.html

Comment: This class haven't initializars, I don't know how to implpement in swift like var myClass = myClass()   https://github.com/kailoa/iphone-smtp/blob/master/Classes/NSData%2BBase64Additions.m

Comment: You are using a class category which is simply adding a method to NSData instances (and some static class methods to the entire class). In swift this is called an extension.

Comment: HOw to declare this? I can't add this code:  extension NSData+Base64Additions {
    
    }